# Video and pictures on gmediarender

Tags: pi-3, media-server

I managed to get audio with bubbleupnp from my android device to my RPi 3 that runs gmediarender, but when I try video it only outputs audio and no video. I can't understand is it even possible to stream video and pictures to gmediarender or is it strictly audio? If it's only audio are there any software to turn RPi into UPnP media renderer?

Comment: First have you looked at what gMediaRenders is capable to do? And what media format have you tried to send (codec)?

Comment: @MatsKarlsson I tried to send mp4 video, as far as I can understand, gmediarender writes that it can get those kind of videos. And I can't understand if gmediarender is even capable of outputing anything except of audio

Comment: A/V that is an acronym used in gmediarender stands for Audio/Video. And have a look at http://uklinuxinfo.blogspot.com/2013/06/streaming-mp4-videos-from-android.html